# Copying input to output without unnecessary Spaces in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C that copies its input to its output while replacing each string of one or more Spaces with a single Space.
My code isn't doing that but is instead taking away every second character. 
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    int lastc;

    lastc = 0;

    while(getchar() != EOF){
        c = getchar();
        if(c == 32 && lastc == 32)
            ;
        else
            putchar(c);
        lastc = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop should look like:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(c == 32 && lastc == 32)
        ;
    else
        putchar(c);
    lastc = c;
}
```

In your version you get a char with getchar while checking the condition for the while loop and then as a next step you again get a char with getchar. So the first one is not used in your code. Therefore it is taking away every second character.

Answer (score 0):

Keep running in while loop until you get non-space character and print just one space after you get out.

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    bool space=false;

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        while (isspace(c)) {
            space = true;
            c = getchar();
        }
        if (space) {
            putchar(' ');
            space = false;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `fgets()` function to getting string from input i.e stdin and store in the scroll string.

Then you must implement a way to analyze string to find spaces in it.

When you find first space, increase index if you face another space.

This is the code.

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    char scroll[100];// = "kang  c    heng    junga";
    fgets(scroll, 100, stdin);
    printf ("Full name: %s\n", scroll);


    int flag = 0;
    int i=0;
    while (scroll[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (scroll[i] == ' ' )
            flag=1;//first space find

        printf("%c",scroll[i]);

        if (flag==0){       
                i++;
        }else {
            while(scroll[i]==' ')
                i++;
            flag=0;     
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample input**: `Salam be    shoma doostane   aziz`

**Program output**: `Salam be shoma doostane aziz`

**[Edit]**

Use new string `st` to hold space eliminated string an print as output.

Also this code work for Persian string.

```
char scroll[100]={0};// = "kang  c    heng    junga";
printf("Enter a string: ");
fgets(scroll, 100, stdin);

printf ("Original string: %s\n", scroll);

char st[100]={0};

int flag = 0;
int i=0;
int j=0;

while (scroll[i] != '\0')
{
    if (scroll[i] == ' ' )
        flag=1;//first space find

    st[j]=scroll[i];
    j++;    

    if (flag==0){       
            i++;
    }else {
        while(scroll[i]==' ')
            i++;
        flag=0; 
    }

}

printf("Eliminate Spaces: %s", st);
```

[image]